# swift tableview height and cell last index

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

While I was developing using a table view, I found something I didn't know. When the height of the cell is 94, the height of the table view is automatically changed according to the number of cells.

```
        makeTableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(possibleLabel.snp.bottom).offset(10)
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(282)
        }
```

Now, the height of the table view is fixed in that way. How can we automatically change the height of the tableview?
Also, I want to make one of the elements of the cell invisible only at the last index of the cell.

```
    private func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        if products.count - 1 == indexPath.row {
            let cell = (cell as! MakeTableViewCell)
            cell.makeView.underLine.isHidden = true
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = (cell as! MakeTableViewCell)
            cell.make.underLine.isHidden = true
        }
        return cell
    }
```

I wrote the code like this, but I don't think I can access the last index. What's the problem?

Comment: Where are you changing the cell's height?  Are you doing it inside of the delegate?  I Would expect to implement `func tableView(UITableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` in the `UITableViewDelegate`. Then, when you want the cell's height to change, I would call `func reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation)`

Comment: @ScottThompson The height of the cell has been designated as follows.
``` makeTableView.rowHeight = 94````